# Validation Plugin

Tags: validation, cmd, jira, jira-plugin

I want to learn how to add validation plugin at Jira so I am following https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/creating-workflow-extensions/? tutorials part 3. When step 3.1 I faced build failure error could anybody help me

TY

Osman

https://pasteboard.co/IgUNSjj.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you update your atlassian SDK to the latest version and also change the maven-jira-plugin to jira-maven-plugin for the plugin

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${amps.version}</version>
```

At the time of writing this answer, put the value of amps.version to 8.0.0 after upgrading your SDK.

I hope this helps you.